# How to configure Json Request and Response with Spring

Tags: json, hibernate, spring

I want to configure my application to send and receive Json objects.I searched on the net I found different solution but whinch one is the best or easy to implement.Things,I want,are to send Object For example ,Category hibernate entity,I want to send List as Json output or , I want to get Category class as Json Object and I'll save it database in my controller function.

Comment: Don't search the net. Read the Spring reference documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to implement a message converter in Spring.
Refer to http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html#rest-message-conversion (JSON messageconverter already exists in Spring 3.0.5 release)